# Problema ao gravar dados no Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql

Tenho duas tabelas no postgres (PRODUTO e CATEGORIA)

Na tabela PRODUTO tenho os CAMPOS -> ID, nomeProduto, descricao, valor, **ID_categoria**.

Na tabela CATEGORIA tenho os CAMPOS -> ID_categoria e nomeCategoria.

No meu projeto no Visual Studio, criei um formulário para gravar novas categorias. Informando somente um NOME ex.(Perfume, Acessorios etc).

E também tenho um formulário para cadastro de PRODUTOS onde são necessário informar o Nome do produto, descrição, valor e **selecionar um código de categoria que encaixe** (escolher na combobox)

O meu problema é agora: Não consigo gravar o formulário do PRODUTO pois a COMBOBOX está relacionada com o NOME da CATEGORIA, pois a pessoa precisa saber o que irá selecionar e não ver os códigos. E no POSTGRES o campo é INTEGER (ID_categoria), logo não grava o NOME.

**Evento LOAD do form PRODUTO. (antigo)**

```
 private void CadastroProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        banco conexao = new banco(); // Classe de conexão.

        // Como carregar dados que estão no PostgreSQL no ComboBox

        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao.conecta(); // Abre conexão
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from categoria"; // Seleciona a tabela
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Executa a busca
        try
        {
            NpgsqlDataReader ler = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ; // Leitura de dados

            while (ler.Read()) // Enquanto tiver campos para ler 
            {
                cmbCategoriaProduto.Items.Add(ler["nome"]); 
            }
            ler.Close();
            ler.Dispose();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        conexao.desconecta();
    }
```

**Evento LOAD do FORM atualizado (Atualizado: 05/10):**

```
private void CadastroProduto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        banco conexao = new banco(); // Classe de conexão.

        // Como carregar dados que estão no PostgreSQL no ComboBox

        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao.conecta(); // Abre conexão
        cmd.CommandText = "Select cod_categoria, nome from categoria"; // Seleciona a tabela
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Executa a busca
        try
        {
            NpgsqlDataReader ler = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ; // Leitura de dados
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("cod_categoria", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("nome", typeof(string));
            dt.Load(ler);

            cmbCategoriaProduto.DisplayMember = "nome";
            cmbCategoriaProduto.ValueMember = "cod_categoria";
            cmbCategoriaProduto.DataSource = dt;
           // while (ler.Read()) // Enquanto tiver campos para ler 
           //{
           //     cmbCategoriaProduto.Items.Add(ler["nome"]); 
           // }
            ler.Close();
            ler.Dispose();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        conexao.desconecta();
    }
```

**Evento SelectedIndex do ComboBox**

```
private void cmbCategoriaProduto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = cmbCategoriaProduto.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

Mesmo assim da erro ao gravar: Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Atributos e métodos**

```
// Atribulos
    private string Nome;
    private string Descricao;
    private double Valor;
    private string cCategoria;

    //metodo construtor
    public produto(string pn, string pd, double pv, string pccat)
    {
        Nome = pn;
        Descricao = pd;
        cCategoria = pccat;
        Valor = pv;

    }
```

**Classe Produto - Método Incluir();**

```
public void IncluirProduto()
    {
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conexao.conecta(); // Instacia o metodo conecta() que está na classe BANCO
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into produto (nome, descricao, cod_categoria, valor) values(@nome,@descricao,@cod_categoria,@valor)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@nome", Nome)); // atributo e campo declarado banco de dados.
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@descricao", Descricao));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@cod_categoria", cCategoria));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@valor", Valor));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexao.desconecta(); // instancia o metodo desconecta() que está na classe BANCO
    }
```

**Botão Cadastrar**

```
private void btnCadastrarProduto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            produto pdt = new produto(txtNomeProduto.Text, txtDescricaoProduto.Text, Convert.ToDouble(txtValorProduto.Text),cmbCategoriaProduto.Text);
            pdt.IncluirProduto();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto Incluso com sucesso!");        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)    
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Da uma lida na sua pergunta, esta meio confusa. Não consegui entender direito qual o problema e qual seria o resultado esperado. O código que você postou não parece ter nada com sua duvida.

Comment: Veja se ficou mais claro @ChristianBeregula

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica, o código que tinha na pergunta tem alguns problemas de robustez mas não tem a ver com seu problema. E não acho que o problema está tão claro ainda. Será que é um problema só de SQL? Caso de pegar chave estrangeira?

Comment: @ChristianBeregula Desculpe a demora para responde-lo demorei um pouco. Então, apliquei exatamente como o site da msdn faz, mesmo assim qnd vai gravar da erro.

Comment: Que erro aparece? esse evento SelectedIndexChanged é só isso mesmo? se for o erro esta ali, atualizando o id como variável local. Tem como postar o evento do SAVE?

Comment: @ChristianBeregula coloquei a foto do erro que da, basicamente é que o campo tem que gravar int, mas não sei onde mexo mais

Comment: O código do botão CADASTRAR, posta ele. o erro certamente esta lá.

Comment: @ChristianBeregula atualizei

Comment: o erro esta aqui -> `cmbCategoriaProduto.Text` onde vc cria o novo produto

Comment: Não sei o que faço mais. Tenho que converter para int. Já tentei mas da erro  FormatException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pude entender,

você está preenchendo o combobox usando realizando uma consulta ao banco de dados e nessa consulta você recebe somente o nome da categoria. A tabela dos produtos possui somente o identificador da categoria.

Se for esse o problema, pode ser solucionado das seguintes formas:

Primeira solução, nesta [pergunta](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9387c998-3373-4d58-85dc-87bb9234e108/how-to-fill-combo-box-from-database-using-c?forum=csharplanguage) a situação é parecida. O que você pode fazer é que a consulta para preencher o combobox tenha as duas colunas, identificador e nome da categoria, e use a propriedade **ValueMember** para a coluna **Id_Categoria** e a propriedade *DisplayMember* para a coluna *nomeCategoria*. Como é apresentado no exemplo da [pergunta](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9387c998-3373-4d58-85dc-87bb9234e108/how-to-fill-combo-box-from-database-using-c?forum=csharplanguage).

Segunda solução, se os nomes das categorias não se repetirem na tabela, faça uma nova busca pelo nome da categoria selecionada na tabela de categorias buscando o identificador e preencha na tabela produtos (não gosto da ideia).

Comment: É isso mesmo @Filipe, irei colocar o código onde carrego a combobox - evento Load do form Produto. Se puder dar uma olhada

Comment: Exatamente! Você poderá aplicar a solução da pergunta que apresentei, ou a solução do @ChristianBeregula, que também é excelente.

Answer (score 3):

Você poderia utilizar um dictionary na hora de carregar sua combobox.

```
Dictionary<string, int> options = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//função que você chama para carregar seu combobox
//dentro do loop de leitura do banco de dados
options.Add(nomeCategoria, ID_categoria);
```

Agora onde você chama o Save do seu form, você só precisa recuperar o id equivalente ao nome da categoria.

```
int idDesejado;
options.TryGetValue(nomeSelecionado, out idDesejado)
```

Comment: Irei tentar está forma. Depois digo o que deu. Valeu